# Using jQuery's selectors contain & closest inside my CSS selector is this possible

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have defined the following script to hide certian table TR:-

```
$('.ms-formtable nobr:contains("Question")').closest('tr').hide();
```

but not sure if i can using pure CSS approach to achieve the same result ?. can anyone adivce on this please?

Comment: I've changed the tags CSS and CSS-Selectors to jQuery and jQuery-Selectors. `:contains` and `.closest()` are not CSS-Selectors themselves.

Comment: You should have a look at this for the `contains` statement: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value_contains.asp

Comment: @JamesDonnelly so is there a way to achieve the same using css selectors/

Comment: @johnG i don't think we have any parent selector in css1,2 or 3. There might be possibility in css4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this isn't possible with pure CSS.

First, CSS `:contains` pseudo-class has been removed from CSS3, so `nobr:contains("Question")` is no more a valid CSS selector.

Second, CSS can select children and descendants, e.g. `.foo > .bar` selects the class `bar` that's a child of the class `foo`. But it doesn't have any way to go the other direction, there's no way to select a parent/ancestor based on a child.